# Javascript changing iframe src doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

On my website I wrote a function like this:

```
function apri(dat) {
document.getElementId('dado').src= dat;
}
```

and the iframe HTML code is the following.

```
<iframe id="dado"src="http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/" width="100%" height="700px" scrolling="yes" frameBorder="0">
  Your browser doesn't load this iframe.
</iframe>
```

I call the `apri()` function in this way:

```
<p onclick="apri(http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/staffpage.html)"> <img src="/pictures/uno.png" /> Staffers</p>
```

The content of my iframe is not changing. I've googled this a lot but I didn't find any solution. What can I do?

Do you think I should use something different instead of the iframe?

Comment: You have 'getElementId'. Did you mean 'getElementById' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your error console after you click the text. You will see an error message.

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

The bug is quoting problem. You have a string with no quotes around it.

```
<p onclick="apri('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/staffpage.html')">
                 ^                                                    ^
              missing                                               missing
```

Comment: I found another error I made. If you look at apri() I wrote 'document. *getElementId* ('dado').src=', It should be *getElementById*. Add this in the answer, it could help other users ;)